# Looping a javascript if statement until it's not true

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**My goal**

I am filling A4 sheets (PDF's) with dynamic content and need to make as many pages as needed

**My implementation, so far**

I have a div(A4 size) that with a fixed height. I want to fill it with dynamic content. 
If the content is too high for the div, I want to make a new div(A4 size) like the first and transfer content from the first div to the last until the remaining content fit inside the first div. If the content on the second div is to high I'll make a third div(A4 size).

Here's my javascript. But calling a function inside it self makes the browser hang

```
function make_new_page(content_height ){
  if ((content_height) > 805){
   var page_count =  $('.wrapper').length
   var last_line = $('.line').last()
   $('#container').append('<div class="wrapper" id="wrapper' + page_count + '"></div>');
   $('#wrapper' + page_count - 1).remove(last_line)
   $('#wrapper' + page_count).append(last_line);
   var content_height = $('.content_height').height();
   make_new_page(content_height)
  }
}

var content_height = $('.content_height').height();
make_new_page(content_height)
```

Comment: Change if to while maybe?

Comment: `content_height` keeps growing but the test `content_height > 805` ensures you keep recrusing.

Comment: @Jasen No, sorry if it's unclear. Each time I do  '.remove(last_line)', 'content_height' gets smaller

Comment: Throw a `console.log(content_height)` in your function to be sure.

Comment: @ChrisHardie `console.log(content_height)` gives me first 880 and on the next line 
1541 778, 1541 is climbing fast. I am now using `while` in stead of `if`

Comment: if your content_height never goes below 805 then the function will keep running over and over without stopping.

Comment: @Jage Yes, but it does. The first time it's 880 and the next time around its stuck at 778

Comment: Could you post the HTML? It's a little hard to wrap my head around this with just div classes and ID's.

Comment: No where in your example code are you looping.

Comment: I did not test but think to put a `return` in an else. Log the `content_height` to look a content_height less than 806.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are likely having a scoping problem. In your code, you declare the content_height variable globally, then you pass it into your function so it can use it locally. Then you unnecessarily redeclare the content_height variable again later in your function after you have already used it locally, when you could have accessed it globally the entire time. If you don't fix those, who knows how the browser will handle that? Different browsers might even handle it differently.

Your function should probably look more like this before you can proceed making this work the way you want:

```
function make_new_page(){
  if ( content_height > 805){
   var page_count =  $('.wrapper').length
   var last_line = $('.line').last();
   $('#container').append('<div class="wrapper" id="wrapper' + page_count + '"></div>');
   $('#wrapper' + page_count - 1).remove(last_line)
   $('#wrapper' + page_count).append(last_line);
   content_height = $('.content_height').height();
   make_new_page();
  }
}

var content_height = $('.content_height').height();
make_new_page();
```